# Update Priority of Cases related to another Case through a Junction Object

Tags: apex, trigger, case, field-update, junction-object

We have a junction object called "Related_Development_Cases__c" that has 2 many-to-many relationships to the Case object through 2 Case lookup fields (Support_Case__c and Development_Case__c).

We have a Case record type called "Tech Request" that we have syncing with our instance of JIRA. Each "Tech Request" Case record represents a ticket in JIRA. We use the junction object to relate our support Case records (identified by the record type "Support Issue") to a "Tech Request" Case record.

What we're looking for is a trigger to update the "Priority" field of the related support Cases to match the Priority value on the "Tech Request" Case record. For example, the Priority field on the "Tech Request" Case is marked as "High", and that should trigger the Priority field on all of the related "Support Issue" Cases to be updated to "High".

I feel like I understand how to do this when parent and child relationships, but the junction object being the in-between record is making it more difficult to grasp how to write the logic. I'm fairly new to APEX, and thought I would reach out here before spending hours trying to code this myself.

**Updated**: *Below is the code I currently have that saved without error, although I know it is not correct. Again, I'm very new to APEX, so please forgive my ignorance if this code is way off from what I'm trying to accomplish.*

```
trigger updateSupportPriority on Case (after update){
    Set<Id> devCases = new Set<Id>();
    List<Related_Development_Cases__c> supportCases = new List<Related_Development_Cases__c>();

    for (Case dev: Trigger.new) {
        Case oldDev = Trigger.oldMap.get(dev.Id);

        if (dev.Priority != oldDev.Priority) { 
            devCases.add(dev.Id); // Tech Request Cases with Priority field updates
        }
    }

    for (Related_Development_Cases__c support: [SELECT Development_Case__r.Priority, Development_Case__c, Support_Case__r.Priority FROM Related_Development_Cases__c WHERE Development_Case__r.Id in :devCases]) {
        support.Support_Case__r.Priority = support.Development_Case__r.Priority;
        supportCases.add(support);
    }

    if (!supportCases.isEmpty()) {
        update supportCases;
    }
}
```

**Below is the code I ended with which is working great...**

```
trigger updateSupportPriority on Case (after update){
    Set<Id> devCases = new Set<Id>();
    List<Case> supportCases = new List<Case>();

    Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Tech Request').getRecordTypeId();

    for (Case dev: Trigger.new) {
        Case oldDev = Trigger.oldMap.get(dev.Id);

        if (dev.Priority != oldDev.Priority && dev.RecordTypeId == devRecordTypeId) { 
            devCases.add(dev.Id);
        }
    }

    for (Related_Development_Cases__c support: [SELECT Development_Case__r.Priority, Development_Case__c, Support_Case__r.Priority FROM Related_Development_Cases__c WHERE Development_Case__r.Id in :devCases]) {
        support.Support_Case__r.Priority = support.Development_Case__r.Priority;
        supportCases.add(support.Support_Case__r);
    }

    if (!supportCases.isEmpty()) {
        update supportCases;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: you just query all support cases which are tagged to this tech request case  and update them through trigger. Can you add the code to the question and say where you need help.

Comment: I have added my current code. The trouble I am having is grabbing the related "Support Issue" Cases. I'm not sure how to identify them by querying the junction object, and updating those related Case records to match the "Tech Request" Case record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're querying and attempting to update the junction object `Related_Development_Cases__c`, but the data change you actually want to make is on the related `Case` itself. You can't make a change on a related object through a relationship field and persist it by updating the linked object like you do here.

Instead of accumulating `Related_Development_Cases__c` instances, you need a `List<Case>`. Your `for` loop then needs to add `support.Support_Case__r` to that list to be updated.

You have a bit of an issue here insofar as this is a many-to-many relationship, so you may want to add logic to cope with the possibility that your Support Case might be associated to Development Cases which have different priorities, and decide how you want to handle that.

I'll also note that your code is not currently filtering the updated Cases in the trigger set based on record type.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and direction! I added the record type filtering and other changes you suggested and it worked perfectly. For the many-to-many relationship issue, it's something we thought of but the internal team here just wants the most recently updated dev case to update the priority for the related support cases. It's a rare situation where a support case would be related to multiple dev cases. I added my end-result on the code to my post above just in case you have further critiques. I'm trying to learn best practices and would appreciate any additional feedback.

Comment: Only thing I see is to get rid of `if (!supportCases.isEmpty()) {`. DML on an empty list is a no-op, so there's no need to do that. Looks solid to me. If you went to a one-to-many relationship instead of a junction object you could achieve some simplification, but that's a larger change.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again for the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: My pleasure, and good luck!